# How to run a command only if is the master branch in travis-ci?

Tags: python, sh, travis-ci, fabric

I have a open-source project and i want to deploy the code just if the code is in the master branch, i already tried many approachs, like:

```
- if [[ $TRAVIS_BRANCH == 'master' ]]; then fab deploy; fi
```

Or something like:

```
BRANCH = "master"

def _get_local_branch():
    return local("git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD", capture=True)

def deploy():
    local_branch = _get_local_branch()
    if local_branch == BRANCH:
        print green("Deploy succefully done!")

    print yellow("Deploy allowed just in the master branch.")
```

But this not work, even in the other peoples branches, the `fab deploy` command was triggered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure why your first approach doesn't work but I would suggest using the `deploy:` directive in your .travis.yml file with a custom deployment script like this:

```
deploy:
  provider: script
  script: scripts/deploy.sh
  on:
    branch: master
```

Here is the [documentation](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/script/).

Hope this helps.